# Best approach to get current state from ledger

Tags: corda

Given that a list of states is shown on a web interface, and there's an "update" option on that interface (and consequently, I need to implement an amendment flow), what would be the best approach to get the StateAndRef of the current state?

1. Store the transaction ID from the create command and use it to get the current StateAndRef
2. By the linearID of the current state
3. It doesn't matter.

Thanks
Maka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `LinearState`, I'd recommend retrieving the latest version of the state you want to spend using its `linearId`:

```
val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(linearId))
val iouStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultQueryService.queryBy<IOUState>(queryCriteria).states.single()
```

The first line creates a query object to retrieve the state by `linearId`. By default, queries only retrieve the latest version (the "head") of the state chain. The second line uses the query to retrieve the object from the vault.

See https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html for details.